# How to set focus on android keyboard's any key programatically when it pops up

Tags: android, bluetooth, navigation, android-keypad

I am looking to develop an app where I can send text over the Bluetooth to another device which I have implemented successfully. Now I have an Edittext in my layout and has set it on focus to popup the keypad which is working fine. I want to control that popped up keypad Navigation. I want when keypad pops up any default key is selected there and when I  send different key codes like '1' for up '2' for down I should be able to see the forth and back movement on the popped up keypad. Is there way I can set a key on focus when it pops up and How can I move to back and forth keys on that keypad. i have goggled alot and have not been able to find any concrete solution to my problem.
Any idea how can I achieve this would e great.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solved your problem?!